# How to change dataframe to time series

Tags: r, time-series

In R ,when I want to change data.frame to time series using funtion `ts()` , the date variable in the resule is number .How to handle it ? Thanks!

```
row_data <- data.frame(mydate=as.Date(c('2013-1-1','2023-1-6','2023-1-20')),
           amount = c(1,7,8))

ts(row_data)
```

Comment: ts is normally used with monthly, quarterly or annual data and does not work at all with irregularly spaced data and does not work well with Date class. You can use the zoo or xts packages.  `library(zoo); z <- read.zoo(row_data)`  From there you can use `as.ts(z)` but what you get may not make sense depending on your probelm.

Comment: The origian question is  i want to draw chart with  quantmod::chartSeries().   quantmod::chartSeries() need input time   time series. Use ts() will make the chart x label are number (I want to show the date as the original format ) . Thanks!

Comment: `chartSeries` works with zoo and xts.

Comment: You can also use the tsibble package with `as_tsibble(row_data, index = mydate)`. More information about time series analysis with tsibbles here: https://otexts.com/fpp3/tsibbles.html